# get Facebook user details using graph api in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I am using Graph API for the first time. I want to fetch user info using this but I have no any idea how to proceed. I only worked with Graph API Explorer.

I want to fetch Facebook info using Graph API.

Comment: That are more questions in one. What did you try? What ressources did you alredy read? We're not here to do the work for you.

Comment: http://www.google.com.. search `get Facebook user details using graph api in iOS` .... https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user.

Comment: Oh lord, why hath thou forsaken us?

Comment: ok.I will never ask these type questions.I  solve this at my own .Thanks .I really apologise for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Graph Explorer then type me & scroll & click on Get Code...then choose your language & get code.

[image]

Comment: @ Moseph:-yeah.i have done this.Can we only need this code to show info or any  method else?

Comment: It gives error.When i set get code on to view did load of file.Declaration of 'FBSDKGraphRequest' must be imported from module 'FBSDKCoreKit.FBSDKGraphRequest' before it is required.

Comment: which type information you need like email,birthdate

Comment: you must be add facebook sdk & import the header file other wise it's give error

Comment: if you have helped my answer please accept & up vote

Comment: i want name email mobile . i remove error but in my nslog there is nothing showing...

Comment: Could you tell me  where i write this code to get proper output.In app delegate or in view controller?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94086/discussion-between-moseph-and-harsh-chauhan).